# Running SQL file in command line using sqlplus result with an error

Tags: oracle, command-line, sqlplus

Using ORACLE 12.0c and SQL Developer.

I try to run a SQL file (myfile.sql) in command line using *sqlplus*:
`sqlplus username/password@schema @myfile.sql` resulted with an error.

I run only *sqlplus* with connection parameters `sqlplus username/password@schema` and still receive an error (see screenshot).

[image]

Typing the *username* and *password* didn't help as well.

Only running *sqlplus* and supply the database domain, port and database name I managed to connect and run the file.

The database is defined in *SQL Developer*, but I don't see it in `TNSNames.ora`.

What am I missing?

Comment: you connect user/password@SERVICE - that's the entry in your tnsnames file. or you can say @server:port/SID|SERVICE

Comment: Correct, that was the only way that I managed to connect and run the file - my question is "**why?** The database and schema are defined in SQL Developer. What configuration am I missing?

Comment: if you want to connect just using a service name, you need a tnsnames.ora file with that information listed...your db has a network configuration assistant (GUI) that will help you build this for you

Comment: you can also open a text editor and just create the tnsnames file manually

Comment: When is the location of *tnsnames* file? Ok, I found it at */ORACLE/product/12.1.0/client_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give credit to @thatjeffsmith and the answer is... see screenshot:
[image]